# How to get elementID from within another function

Tags: javascript, imagemap

I have some code:

```
function new_training() {
document.getElementById("training").style="";
tr++;
var newDiv = $('#training div:first').clone();
newDiv.attr('id', tr);
var delLink = 'This is item ' + tr + '<select name=priority> <option value="1">1</option> <option value="2">2</option> <option value="3">3</option> </select> <a class="btn btn-danger" style="text-align:right;margin-right:65px" href="javascript:deltr(' + tr + ')" > Delete Item ' + tr + ' </a>';
newDiv.find('tr:first th').text('Item ' + tr);
newDiv.append(delLink);
$('#training').append(newDiv);
newDiv.find('input:text').val('');
}
```

Which work good.

What i am trying to do is get the id of the element i click form an image map.

```
<area id="cupandplates" alt="" title="cupandplates" href="javascript:new_training()" shape="rect" coords="212,127,295,196" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area id="3cups" alt="" title="3cups" href="javascript:new_training()" shape="rect" coords="313,147,415,201" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area id="beerstines" alt="" title="beerstines" href="javascript:new_training()" shape="rect" coords="200,231,269,290" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
```

If i use this fuction:

```
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
alert(clicked_id);
}
```

And change my area's

```
<area id="cupandplates" alt="" title="cupandplates" href="javascript:new_training()" onClick="reply_click(this.id)" shape="rect" coords="212,127,295,196" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area id="3cups" alt="" title="3cups" href="javascript:new_training()" onClick="reply_click(this.id)" shape="rect" coords="313,147,415,201" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area id="beerstines" alt="" title="beerstines" href="javascript:new_training()" onClick="reply_click(this.id)" shape="rect" coords="200,231,269,290" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
```

It will alert the proper ID

What i get now is:

This is item 1 Delete Item 1

This is item 2 Delete Item 2

This is item 3 Delete Item 3

Im not sure what to change to make it so i get:

This is cupandplates Delete Item 1

This is 3cups Delete Item 2

This is beerstines Delete Item 3

Any help would be great.

Comment: do you not want to pass the id as a param in new_training `href="javascript:new_training(this.id)"` and then `function new_training(id) { document.getElementById(id).style=""; //etc.. }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have almost solved your own problem.

It looks like you are looking for title attribute values from area element
Instead of passing the id pass the event trigger object as a whole

```
<area id="cupandplates" alt="" title="cupandplates" href="javascript:new_training()" onClick="reply_click(this)" shape="rect" coords="212,127,295,196" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area id="3cups" alt="" title="3cups" href="javascript:new_training()" onClick="reply_click(this)" shape="rect" coords="313,147,415,201" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area id="beerstines" alt="" title="beerstines" href="javascript:new_training()" onClick="reply_click(this)" shape="rect" coords="200,231,269,290" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
```

and then access the title by using

```
function reply_click(element)
{
  alert(element.getAttribute("title"));
}
```

Comment: How can i pass the value form function reply_click(element) to function new_training() and use as a variable?

Comment: Call new_training() from reply_click() and remove href="javascript:new_training()"

Comment: when i am adding     var delLink = 'This is item ' + tr + '<select name=priority> <option value="1">1</option> <option value="2">2</option> <option value="3">3</option> </select> <a class="btn btn-danger" style="text-align:right;margin-right:65px" href="javascript:deltr(' + tr + ')" > Delete Item ' + tr + ' </a>'; how do i set the "tr' portion of 'This is item ' + tr + '?

Comment: Instead of tr i want to use the title

Comment: Got it changing the function to: reply_click(element) { itemname = element.getAttribute("title"); new_training(); } Then i can pass itemname. Thanks alot for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the ref to the element when calling:

```
<area id="cupandplates" alt="" title="cupandplates" href="javascript:new_training(this)" shape="rect" coords="212,127,295,196" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area id="3cups" alt="" title="3cups" href="javascript:new_training(this)" shape="rect" coords="313,147,415,201" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area id="beerstines" alt="" title="beerstines" href="javascript:new_training(this)" shape="rect" coords="200,231,269,290" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
```

Then inside the javascript function, use the ref as:

```
function new_training(el)
{
  var id = el.getAttribute("id");
  //use the id
}
```

OR if you directly want to pass the id, then try like this:

```
<area id="cupandplates" alt="" title="cupandplates" href="javascript:new_training(this.id)" shape="rect" coords="212,127,295,196" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
```

Hope it helps

Comment: When using this method i get "undefined'